# How do I create an instance and assign a default value based on a Type parameter?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an array of `Type` objects corresponding to `int`, `bool`, `string`, `float`, `int?` ...

How do I write a function that takes in the above array and returns strongly typed default values for each type in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a default value from a `Type`, simply invoke `Activator.CreateInstance`

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
```

As for the bit about getting a strong type, the problem is that when you use reflection in this manner, it deals in objects. To get a strong type, you would need to know it at compile time, which kind of defeats your purpose. When you're doing these things at runtime, you're left with `object` or `dynamic` (which is just `object` behind the scenes).

Beyond that, if you're talking about running the array through a method and returning default values for each type, you're going to be talking about returning an `IEnumerable<object>` or `object[]` array, as the type of each item would obviously differ.

Comment: Thanks. I can get a list of `Type`s instead of strings [Edited question]. Is there a way to get a strong typed instance from there?